# ZF2 - PaginationControl $this->route not working

Tags: pagination, zend-framework2

in a view I call:

```
<?php echo $this->paginationcontrol($paginator,'Jumping','pagination')?>
```

It works but inside the pagination.phtml the paginatorcontrol calls:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $this->first)); ?>">
First
```

$this->route is not working, it is empty why?

I should pass inside paginationcontrol()?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I should pass inside paginationcontrol()?

Yes, the fourth parameter to paginationcontrol accepts an array which is passed as data to the partial it renders, you should include the route to use there

```
<?php echo $this->paginationcontrol($paginator, 'Jumping', 'pagination', array('route' => 'some/app/route'))?>
```